# Rails 4.0. vendor/assets/javascripts - Asset Pipeline issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am running Rails 4.0.1 and Ruby 2.0.0.  I currently have a graph.js that takes inputs in from the user for a savings calculator in order to create a graph with d3 and the rickshaw.js graph.

My `graph.js` file is saved in the `app/assets/javascripts/graph.js`. I make a call to the Rickshaw graph with

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph()
```

I am getting an error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: Rickshaw is not defined.`

The `rickshaw.js` file is saved in `vendor/javascript/rickshaw.js` along with `d3.layout.js` and `d3.vs.js`.  If I save all of these files in the `app/assets/javascripts` everything works fine, but that does not seem to be the correct rails way.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Thank you.

Comment: What does `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` look like?  Does it have a line to either `require_tree` or `require graph`?

Comment: It has both. //= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
//= require custom.js
//= require graph.js
// Vendor Files
//= require d3.v3.js
//= require d3.layout.js
//= require rickshaw.js

Comment: Also when I deploy to heroku the graphing function no longer works. I do have gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use the asset pipeline, you'll want just the filename in the `require` statements:

```
// Vendor Files
//= require d3.v3
//= require d3.layout
//= require rickshaw
```

See [the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) docs for more info on asset organization.